# Is it possible to select a specific class on @page?

Tags: css, mpdf

I'm working with mPDF and was wondering if there is a way with css to target an element on a specific page?  For example, is there a way to do this to select my "mainContent" div on the first page?:

@page:first .mainContent{width:66%;etc...etc...}

Comment: IIRC @page is actually targeting only the page, you can't target specific elements from this rule... Not sure how what you want to do could be done though... Can't you hardcode the element's page (e.g with [break-before](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/break-before) rules), and then simply use an `@media (print)` rule?

Answer (score -1):

you have to select elements using class or id.